# Prevent call to base assignment operator in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, assignment-operator

I have these two classes in my library:

```
class Base {
    int _handler;
protected:
    Base() = default;

    Base& operator=(int h) {
        this->_handler = h;
        return *this;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
protected:
    Derived() = default;

    void initialize() {
        this->Base::operator=(12345); // internal stuff
    }
};
```

`Derived` class is available to be inherited by the user. He should do this:

```
class User_Class : public Derived {
    void foo() {
        this->initialize();
    }
};
```

But instead, he does this:

```
class User_Class : public Derived {
    void foo() {
        this->Base::operator=(999); // no, you broke it!
    }
};
```

How can I prevent the call to the `Base` assignment operator?

Comment: Just in passing, none of the four uses of `this->` is needed.

Comment: I'm aware of that, it's just for the sake of clarity (even if it's obvious enough). Thanks.

Comment: You could make the assignment operator private, then make `Derived` a friend of `Base`?

Comment: You might make the method `private` (and `Derived` `friend`)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I change the header to this

```
class Derived : private Base
```

the compiler immediately blocks the call to operator= with "cannot access inaccessible member declared in class 'Base'", however the code which calls initialize works normally, because that is accessible.

However, you should also override operator= in Derived, and just have it check whether or not it has been initialized.  Don't make the client class handle internal bookkeeping.

Comment: +1 for the last sentence in particular. Don't rely on your clients knowing to invoke things in the correct sequence.

Comment: As an additional note, if the functions in Derived are not sufficient, then consider an interface class, so they know what they can and can't do (and the compiler knows, too).

Comment: @kenny But then I wouldn't be able to pass an `User_Class` object to a function like `void abc(Base& b)`, right? VC++ gives me error C2243: "conversion from 'User_Class *' to 'Base &' exists, but is inaccessible".

Comment: If you want to restrict the client's access to class internals, then good, but of course you will have some work to do to give the client access to what they do need. For example, why is the client using a function which takes Base?  Shouldn't that be void abc(Derived &d)?

Comment: @kenny Yes, it could be `void abc(Derived& d)`, but then I'd have to write a function call to each of the derived classes of `Base`, which are many. But if my design just reached a "C++ boundary", as it seems, then I understand there's no other way (or just rethink the whole thing).

Comment: If they need part of Base private, and part of Base public, then split Base into two classes? We're way past the scope of the original question, which I answered. What you want is absolutely achievable, but may require some OO redesign. We might even have to use the virtual keyword. :)